# Intelephense / Livewire - Decorators are not valid here

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, laravel-livewire, intelephense

I'm using the [vscode intelephense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client), and writing some JS logic using [laravel livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts#accessing-javascript-component-instance). My objective is to send an event at a specific time to refresh some data.

To achieve this, my logic is something like:

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    const refreshTime = @this.refreshTime;
    setTimeout(() => {
        Livewire.emit('refresh');
    }, refreshTime);
});
```

Although this works, the Intelephense extension reports an error on `@this.refreshTime`:

```
Decorators are not valid here.javascript
Expression expected.javascript
```

Is there any way to prevent or ignore this error? I'm thinking something like `eslint-disable-next-line`, but for intelephense. Solutions that avoid using `@this`, `@js`, and other invalid JS syntax would also be acceptable!

Answer (score 0):

My current solution for this is to populate the data in an element:

```
<div
    class="hidden"
    id="editor-data"
    data-refresh-time="{{ $refreshTime }}"
>
</div>
```

And retrieve the values using the element's dataset. In my case, the element will only appear once per page, so I don't need to worry about ID collisions.

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    const dataEl = document.getElementById('editor-data');
    const refreshTime = parseInt(dataEl.dataset.refreshTime);
    setTimeout(() => {
        Livewire.emit('refresh');
    }, refreshTime);
});
```